# Инициализация OpenGL окна: ошибки сборки в коде на C++

Tags: c++, opengl

ПО статье NeHe написал программу, выводящую OpenGL окно. Добавил в проект заголовочные файлы:

```
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glaux.h>
```

Прописал:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "GLaux.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "GLu32.lib")
```

Сами эти файлы скопировал в директорию, где лежит исходник самой программы. Скомпилировал в MSVS 2008. Вывело 12 ошибок, подобные вот этой:

> `error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 в функции "void __cdecl InitGL(int,int)" (?InitGL@@YAXHH@Z)`

И

> `: fatal error LNK1120: 12 неразрешенных внешних элементов`

Т.е. я в программе вызываю OpenGL'овских функций, и к каждой такой функции ошибка.
Я уже совсем отчаялся. Скажите, пожалуйста, что не так, и что надо сделать, чтобы всё заработало (исходник думаю нет смысла показывать, потому что я его чисто скопировал так же, как было у NeHe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте эту :)

```
#pragma comment(lib, "OpenGL32.lib")
```

P.S. [Первый урок NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_(win32)/13001/) и цитата из него

> After you have created a new Win32 Application (NOT a console application) in Visual C++, you will need to link the OpenGL libraries. In Visual C++ go to Project, Settings, and then click on the LINK tab. Under "Object/Library Modules" at the beginning of the line (before kernel32.lib) add OpenGL32.lib GLu32.lib and GLaux.lib. Once you've done this click on OK. You're now ready to write an OpenGL Windows program.

В которой написано, что к проекту вам нужно дополнительно подключить:

- OpenGL32.lib
- GLu32.lib
- GLaux.lib

Answer (score 2):

Заголовочные файлы и библиотеки openGL - это часть SDK. Возникает вопрос - разворачивали вообще SDK и если нет - откуда взялся opengl32.lib. Скорее всего он или 64-разрядный или под другой компилятор. Смотреть примерно c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте добавить библиотеки в опции (командную строку) компоновщика (linker) - включая пути... Ощущение такое, что он их почему-то не цепляет из #pragma comment(lib...

Вот [здесь](http://thoughtsfrommylife.com/article-748-OpenGL_and_Visual_Studio_Express_2008) есть инструкция по настройке OpenGL для Visual C++/ Возможно, будет полезна. К сожалению, на ангийском.